# Recurring coordinator for hive using oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am facing issue while running the coordinator for hive using oozie. This is how my jobs.properties file looks like:

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=true

workflowRoot=hdfs://bigi-3000-beta-bm-20140511-2204-3467-master.imdemocloud.com:9000/user/nehpraka/price_comp1

start=2015-05-20T22:00Z
end=2015-06-22T23:00Z

# HDFS path of the coordinator app
oozie.coord.application.path=hdfs://bigi-3000-beta-bm-20140511-2204-3467-master.imdemocloud.com:9000/user/nehpraka/price_comp1
```

and this the coordinator.xml

```
<coordinator-app name="my_coord_app" frequency="${coord:hours(1)}" start="${coordStart}" end="${coordEnd}" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4">
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>${workflowRoot}</app-path>
      </workflow>
   </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

But I am getting following error when I am running my job.

```
$OOZIE_HOME/bin/oozie job -run -config price_comp1/job.properties
Error: E1004 : Internal Server Error
```

My workflow is running fine, problem occurred when I tried to append the coordinator.

Answer (score 0):

:) It was an mismatch of the name of variables coordStart and coordend.
Still I have one query, what this Start and End time signsiifies?

Does it mean start and end time for the oozie job?